# Function inside of class is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class that represents an item in my database.

```
class Item{

   constructor(serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Queries database, gets the item and all of it's information
     * @returns query result
     */
    async getItem() {

        //Query database 
        var [rows, fields] = await db.execute('query...', [this.serialNumber]);


        //we have no results, bad entry or is a sales order
        if (rows.length < 1) {
            return rows;
        }

        //checking item
        var check = await _checkIbutton(); //is undefined

        ...

    }

    /**
    * Checks if the item is also an iButton
    * @returns query results if they exist
    */
    async _checkIbutton() {


        var [rows, fields] = await db.execute('Query...', [this.serialNumber]);

        if (rows.length < 1) {
            return { status: false };
        }
        return { status: true, data: rows };
    }

}
```

The function `checkIbutton()` checks if the item is a specific type of item.  When I call that function in `getItem()` I get the error: `ReferenceError: _checkIbutton is not defined.`

_checkIbutton is in the scope of the class and so is getItem.  Why is this error is occuring?

Comment: `this` is your friend.

Comment: Try with `await this._checkIbutton();`

Comment: It's a method, not a function. It's a property of your instance, not a variable that is in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Test {

  constructor() {
      this.func1();
  }

  async func1() {

      console.log("asc");
      await this.func2();
  }

  async func2() {
      console.log("22asc");
  }
}
const test = new Test();
```

you must use this keyword.“this” refers to invoker object (parent object)

Comment: "parent object" is vague and potentially misleading. It's more the invokee than the invoker, the target of the method call. The technical term is *receiver*.